# SegFaults in C/MySQL through Structured Con

Tags: mysql, c, linux

Well, i've been working on this little project for a week or so now as a learning experience as I take C courses.  I've worked it almost error free until now, I was instructed to make *con a struct because I was getting a huge stack dump at the end (which was caused by a pointer problem)

My program works fine, everything.  However upon closing the mysql connection I am getting a segfault.

Code:

```
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct sql {

    MYSQL *con;

};

int try(char getInput[100]) {

   struct sql grab;
   MYSQL_RES *res;
   MYSQL_ROW row;
   char *server = "localhost";
   char *user = "root";
   char *password = "iluvgeordi"; 
   char *database = "test";

    if( strcmp( getInput, "version" ) == 0 )
        printf( "\n->Mysql Version: %s\n", mysql_get_client_info() );
    else if( strcmp( getInput, "get" ) == 0 ) {
    
        grab.con = mysql_init(NULL);
        
        if( !mysql_real_connect(grab.con, server, user, password, database, 0, NULL, 0) ) {
        
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(grab.con));
            exit(1);
        
        }
        
        if( mysql_query(grab.con, "show tables") ) {
            
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(grab.con));
            exit(1);

        }
            
        res = mysql_use_result(grab.con);
        if( res != NULL ) {
            
            while( ( row = mysql_fetch_row(res) ) != NULL )
                printf( "%s \n", row[0] );
            
        }
        mysql_free_result(res); 
    
    }

    mysql_close(grab.con);
    
}
```

Even though I know its the mysql_close, here the GDB Stack Dump/Back Trace

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0xf7cca37e in
> mysql_close () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18 (gdb)
> where
>
> ## 0  0xf7cca37e in mysql_close () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18
>
> ## 1  0x08048afa in try (getInput=0xffffd37c "version") at m-try.c:61
>
> ## 2  0x0804894b in main (argc=1, argv=0xffffd494) at main.c:37 (gdb) bt
>
> ## 0  0xf7cca37e in mysql_close () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18
>
> ## 1  0x08048afa in try (getInput=0xffffd37c "version") at m-try.c:61
>
> ## 2  0x0804894b in main (argc=1, argv=0xffffd494) at main.c:37 (gdb) quit

I know there is 1000's of mysql C questions, however none of them are relavent to what I need otherwise I surely would have found it by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that error is caused by a call of `try( "version" );`:

```
1 0x08048afa in try (getInput=0xffffd37c "version") at m-try.c:61
```

and indeed, you only all `mysql_init()` and assign a value to `grab.con` if you call `try( "get" )` but you always call `mysql_close( grab.con );`

You should just put that call into the "get" branch;

```
....
else if( strcmp( getInput, "get" ) == 0 ) {
    ...
    mysql_close( grab.con );
}
```

Comment: thank you so much.  Sorry if I seem stupid i'm just learning C and how to use GDB and every answer keeps me from having to ask more stupid questions.  I'd triple upvote you if possible.

Comment: don't worry, great I could help. But if you want you can accept the answer to make clear the problem is solved